# Zabbix server installation error

Tags: php, server, zabbix

I am getting the following error trying to install zabbix-server.

> Failed to start zabbix-server.service: Unit zabbix-server.service
>   failed to load: No such file or directory.

I ama ble to run zabbix-agent, but when I am adding another server as host, I am getting following errors:

> Connection to Zabbix server "localhost" refused. Possible reasons:
>   1. Incorrect server IP/DNS in the "zabbix.conf.php";
>   2. Security environment (for example, SELinux) is blocking the connection;
>   3. Zabbix server daemon not running;
>   4. Firewall is blocking TCP connection. Connection refused

Any idea on how to resolve these errors?

Can we check server status only with zabbix-agent instead of zabbix-server?

Comment: This is quite vague. Could it be that you don't have the server packages installed? As for monitoring, Zabbix agent alone cannot do any monitoring.

Comment: I also got this error and i fixed it. i changed ip the in zabbix.conf.php. check whether the ip of zabbix server ius correct or not

Answer (score 1):

Get into the zabbix.conf.php

```
 #vim /etc/zabbix/web/zabbix.conf.php
      ZBX_SERVER      = '**your zabbix ip address or DNS name**';
      ZBX_SERVER_PORT = '10051';
      ZBX_SERVER_NAME = '**your zabbix hostname**';
```

Change the ip address or DNS name you can resolve the error

After that restart the zabbix server

```
# sudo service zabbix-server restart
```

To verify go to Dashboard Administration -> queue there you see data

Answer (score 0):

`Hi,
I have also faced lots of problem while installing zabbix-server. Hence i have compiled proper installation steps here from scratch.`

[setup_zabbix_server_on_centos_redhat_7](https://github.com/vikash32/setup_zabbix_server_on_rpm_distro)

Comment: Not an answer to the OP. If you have some troubles, please ask your own question, with WAY more details than "it doesn't work". We ain't no wizards.

Comment: @SBO : I am not asking any question here, i have simply compiled all the steps which are required for proper installation of zabbix. Be reasonable before downvoting

Comment: My bad, I didn't understand it that way.